# Rails - Active Record :conditions overrides :select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select, conditional-statements

I have a fairly large model and I want to retrieve only a select set of fields for each record in order to keep the JSON string I am building small.

Using :select with find works great but my key goal is to use conditional logic with an associated model. Is the only way to do this really with a lamda in a named scope? I'm dreading that perhaps unnecessarily but I'd like to understand if there is a way to make the :select work with a condition.

This works:

```
@sites = Site.find  :all, :select => 'id,foo,bar'
```

When I try this:

```
@sites = Site.find  :all, :select => 'id,foo,bar', :include => [:relatedmodel],
                  :conditions => ["relatedmodel.type in (?)", params[:filters]]
```

The condition works but each record includes all of the Site attributes which makes my JSON string way way too large.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Are you sure the conditions are the problem? I haven't tested this, but the include looks more suspicious.

Comment: I could be totally confused but doesn't the related model need to be included in order to apply conditions to it?

If I do this @sites = Site.find :all, :select => 'id,foo,bar', :include => :relatedmodel

The 3 attributes in the :select are all the are returned as I'm hoping would happen after the addition of the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [to_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873) call supports `:except` and `:only` options to exclude/include model fields during serialization.

```
@sites.to_json(:only => [:name, :foo, :bar])
```

Call above serializes the `Site` objects with fields `name` and `location`.

```
@sites.to_json(:only => [:name, :location], 
        :include => { :relatedmodel => { 
                          :only => [:description] 
                      } 
                    }
         )
```

Call above serializes the `Site` objects with fields `name`, and `location` and contained `RelatedModel` objects with `description` field.

Comment: This is great. I didn't think about looking at the to_json call as I was hung up on trying to get activerecord to give me what I wanted. This works perfectly and my JSON object is now a reasonable size. Thanks!